# How to check if a field is used in multiple object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I have lookup field for country in many object is it possible to check in one place in Salesforce in how many object this field is being used

Comment: Do you mean how many objects are children of "country"? Or what Visualforce/apex pages and classes is the field being used on?

Comment: One of the SFDC Admin asked if there is a way that she can check how many object in Salesforce using a lookup field i.e. Country in one place rather opening every object and checking if that field is there or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the possible solutions could be the following:

you could use Force.com IDE and search your objects metadata for the wished field name. So you can get the quantity.

Comment: I have run the eclipse and it worked just fine with search all. But if I would like to refine my search for e.g. I want if that country field has a name as united kingdom can I run a query on developer console to find how many object has a company name as United Kingdom and at the same time get there record id as well. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @RohanSharma You can search for labels `<label>Field name</label>` or just use a regular expression, it is really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps less intuitive than you'd like, there is an app on the Salesforce AppExchange called [Metadata Search](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI) which seems to do exactly what you want.

This says you can:

> Quick search Approval Processes, Workflows, Validations, Fields, Objects, Reports, Dashboards, Custom Settings, Apps, Roles, Profiles, Permission Sets, Templates, Groups, Queues, Sites, Record Types, Assignments, Links, Classes, Triggers, Pages etc.

So it seems to do more than you're even asking for here.

Comment: Thanks lot App worked saved lot of time than Eclipse appreciated.